# PHP RESTful Unsupported media type error

Tags: java, php, curl, restful-authentication, glassfish-4

[image]I think it's giving a better performance than it was before. The new development is that though it has not been inserting but at least it issues an understandable error of "Unsupported Media Type" and not displaying code as it was earlier.

What exactly am I to do to correct this error? I'd thought it is because I did not add a content-type, after adding it it gives the same result. I am still running both servers on localhost.

The web service is created in Netbeans using Java while the calling application is created using PHP running under XAMPP. For an overview on the error report see the attached image.

```
<?php

  if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $url = "http://localhost:8080/WMWS/webresources/entity.userregistration";

    $data = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
   $initializeCurl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($initializeCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'Content-type' => "text/plain"
        ));
   curl_setopt($initializeCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($initializeCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($initializeCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($initializeCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   $response = curl_exec($initializeCurl);
   var_dump($response);  // string(37) "{"username":"test","password":"test"}"
   curl_close($initializeCurl);
 }

 ?>

  <body>
      <form method = "POST">
          <label for = "username">Username</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "username" />
          <label for = "password">Password</label>
          <input type = "password" name = "password" />
          <button id = "register" name = "register">Register</button>
      </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: You've referred to an image in your question, but I can't see one. However, if the error is textual it is probably better just to copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: Sorry for omitting to upload it. Thanks.